# .NET Core Cronos Cron Expressions not parsing correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, cron, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the Cronos library to handle my cron jobs on .NET Core.

However I have encountered this issue where the common Cron Expressions are not being parsed in at all. It keeps giving me a CronFormatException.

I have looked through the Github page and used their formats but I still get the same Exceptions.

This is my code:

```
services.AddCronJob<Worker1>(x =>
{
    x.TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
    x.CronExpression = "* * * * * *";
});
```

I want to run it every second but I get the CronFormatException issue.

This is the library:
https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos

Does this library use a different cron format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not specify what you are doing in the `AddCronJob` method, but I guess you are doing a `CronExpression.Parse("* * * * * *")` method call somewhere, and this will throw the exception. To fix it you should change it to `CronExpression.Parse("* * * * * *", CronFormat.IncludeSeconds)` like it says on the github page what you linked: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos#adding-seconds-to-an-expression